# Magento : After upgrading to PHP7.0 the shipping rates return zero in checkout page

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods, php-7

Recently I have upgraded my server with PHP7.0 and checked all the functionalities. Everything seems to be working except the shipping rates on the one-page checkout page.

Once I choose the shipping & billing address it populates the available shipping methods with the zero values.

Also, the shipping rates are not reflected in the orders details page, admin area.

Guide me on this issue.[image]